# Angular 15 Material unable to change default min-height of mat-menu

Tags: angular, angular-material

[Here's an image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDNhg.png)
This is Angular 15 with ngMaterial installed.

I use Chrome Dev tools, select the panel's white space, and that takes me to mat-menu, which is using mat-menu-panel.
I can manually set the min-height to 50px and it looks perfect.
I tried to update it for this specific dropdown - I also tried both mat-menu and mat-menu-item.

When I restart the application, it is as though the style is being ignored - it doesn't appear in the Dev Tools.

No change.

Comment: Can you show the CSS code you are editing to change this?

Comment: A lot of times browsers can overwrite certain styles and you may need to override them. It's not best practice, but you can always check if adding```!important;``` to the end of your style statement works.